# How do i get rid of this "blocky" effect on my mantaflow explosion?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I followed https://developer.blender.org/T74559 and still no luck. Any ideas?

[image: blocky explosion][image: blocky explosion]

Comment: Try higher resolution.

Comment: Yea, i tried 400 without adaptive domain.